# PayTm Transaction Status API

Tags: laravel, api, paytm

I need a help in implementing of paytm payment gateway. i am implementing the gateway in laravel and i have coded it correctly and i have no errors and the sandbox keys are working fine and i am getting the responses also. My Issue is, I need to get the details of a transaction with the transaction ID/TXNID,

I've gone through the doc and found this [https://developer.paytm.com/docs/transaction-status-api/][1]
found almost what i can achieve, But It's getting the parameter of **ORDER_ID** Not **TXN_ID**, Is there any way get the details of transaction via Transaction ID.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such api to get the status of payment via transaction id. Kindly use ORDERID which you sent in the request parameter at the time of transaction..